# Its time to expand what GD is about!

Tags: discussion

Ive seen other graduated sites do this but I've never seen GD do it but I want us, as a community, to possibly reflect or have chat sessions where we can question professionals in the field.  I know in beta we had some talks about this but no one would pull the trigger so I hope I am doing that.  I'm all up for a private chat event where we have a Q&A session, questions will be laid out before the chat event.  Any other ideas people have please let me know on what can be brought to build our community and will allow us to have fun instead of policing new users to follow the yellow brick road.

So what I would like to possibly consider is:

- Chat session with an elite member of the design community; example:  Maria Grønlund
- a chat session with an illustrator,  example: Mike from Creative Mints
- Typography professional who has created a font and discuss what areas or questions we would have when doing one.
- Design contest (tried that once but never went anywhere) like Photography does for photo work.

Comment: I'm all for this! I'd love to know more about what and how designers make their products. Make sure it's recorded! A design contest would be a great learning process, especially if more seasoned members were willing to aid the ones less so (like me)

Comment: If we're opening up the floor for people to talk about things, I'd love to give a talk about UX animations

Comment: Great idea!! :D

Answer (score 5):

I'd be in favor of **Design Tennis** over design contests. It is how I learned Photoshop many years ago and I think very beneficial to the creative process.

For those that don't know, here is how a Tennis / Battle whatever you want to call it works.

People sign up and "volley" the design back and forth. If agreed upon you can exchange working files (PSD/EPS/ETC) but more often than not you just use the .jpg. It can, and has been extended to allow for multiple players. Ideally, you have a set order and number of rounds though I've seen battles go on indefinitely.

For example if myself, vincent, benteh, and yisela wanted to we could either each pair up and have our own "battle" or we could all participate in the same one.

I would start create an image. Then vincent would take that image and make it his own. Then benteh does the same. Then Yisela. Then it goes back to me.

The only thing that remains the same is the size and you should be able to at least see some remnant of the previous person's piece. A texture, an element, something to show you used it in your work.

---

**Update:**

I am creating a starter image and will post it in the newly created room, [Design Volleyball](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21438/design-volleyball), anyone will be welcome to come in and modify whatever the previously posted image is.

Comment: Huh, I thought it was more of a "make a meme" thing, where you take a photo and start doctoring it and adding things to it. Or you all start with the *same* image and everyone does something different with it.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I've never done it with a "meme." I have done same image, generally once a month someone puts up an image and everyone goes off that. We never call that "Tennis" or "Battle" though because there's no back and forth.

Comment: A little like the contests on Worth1000, back before it got too complex and weird.